# Why does my site stop scrolling when using touch devices?

Tags: html, mobile, scroll

I have a html site which works well on any device which uses a mouse or scrollwheel. However when I test on mobile, my site scrolls smoothly for a certain amount of time, and pauses at the bottom of a section as if it has reached the bottom of the page.

After about half a second the site works as usual, but if I scroll back up the page the same issue occurs.

I have tried adding `webkit-overflow-scrolling` to all classes and most of the resolutions to this problem I find are based on this methodology. But It's not fixing things in my case.

If it helps, when I scroll to the point where the site pauses, chrome's (mobile) toolbar disappears as if I have reached the bottom of the page and swiped it away.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Give your website's link or show the code of webpage.

Comment: Ok so after a bunch of testing I've realised that the `grid.framework.less` file  is adding `margin-left:-15px` and `margin-right:-15px` to any bootstrap row. 

When I remove these margins the scrolling works fine, but the page is no longer my desired width. 

I've also noticed that when I scroll with touch, a new webkit scrollbar shows up when I move past the div that's causing the issue.